# How to keep two directories on two unconnected machines in sync via emailing of delta-archives

Tags: backup, sync, rsync, unison

My situation is that I have two directories on two different computers (one Windows machine, OSX machine) and I need to keep the two directories on the two machines in sync (= mirrored), so that they contain the same files and subdirectories. The files in the directories are text files, images and the occasional binary file.

My Problem is that the two machines are not connected via LAN/WAN. **The only way to move data between them is via email.**

So I'm looking for a way to sync the directories by emailing back and forth small delta-archives which I than can extract on each machine. How can I do this with a tool like `rsync` or `unsion`? I figure, the system needs to maintain a tracking file which contains a list of all files with timestamps from the other machine effectively remembering that machine's "last seen" state.

Comment: *Note: The state of affairs at the beginning, when the sync system starts out, is that both directories are already very similar, only a few files are different and I guess the system should start with creating the mentioned "last seen" file lists. Can `rsync`, `unison` or a similar tool do this?*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Mercurial with PatchBomb and Mbox extesions.

The entry point for getting knowledge is here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommunicatingChanges

Comment: Does Mercurial work well with images and binaries? I had discussed a solution with git, but git works only well for text files.

Comment: From [Mercurial: Binary Files](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BinaryFiles) I deduct that Mercurial *does* work well with binary files. I will try a Mercurial-based system out.